# How to get various types used in a C# project with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, built-in-types, roslyn-code-analysis

I am analyzing about converting an existing C# library to java. To start with I need to know what are the types / built-in keywords used in the existing C# library. I mean, for example

```
public class CSharpClass
{
int i;
float j;
Console.Writeline(String.Concat("A","B"));
}
```

In this class the types/Keywords used are,

1. public
2. int
3. float
4. Console
5. String

My Questions are,

1. Is there any way to do this. I hope I can do this with Roslyn. But we can get “LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax” for variables. But how to parse “Console” and “Concat”. Is that “Sytax walker” that parses all the tokens in a class is the only option?
2. Also how to get all the classes from a project file with Roslyn?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly do you want and why? Why do you talk about types and then include `public` in the list? Do you care only about explicitly mentioned types, or also implicitly? For example, if the code was `var x = new int[0].ToList();`, should the types `Enumerable` and `List<int>` (or `List<T>`?) be included?

Comment: Console and String are not keywords.  Are you looking for keywords or identifiers (or types of tokens)?  Or, do you want a level higher and know about all the symbols?

Answer (score 3):

You need to semantics as well -- syntax is just the text you see and that's exactly what you get, nothing more, nothing less. Get a `Compilation` for your project, then you can call `GetSemanticModel` where you give it a tree, and then from there you can call `GetTypeInfo` or `GetSymbolInfo` (as appropriate, search online for the difference between these two) to get type information.

As far as getting the `Compilation`, if you're writing a command line tool you probably want to use `MSBuildWorkspace` to load your project. If you're analyzing the projects open in Visual Studio, use `VisualStudioWorkspace`, etc.